# Parse Android fails to download image with a moved permanently error

Tags: android, nginx, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

I am getting the following exception when trying to download a ParseFile using `getData()` method.

```
com.parse.ParseException: Download from S3 failed. Moved Permanently
  at com.parse.ParseAWSRequest.onResponseAsync(ParseAWSRequest.java:43)
  at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:137)
  at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:133)
  at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
  at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
  at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
  at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715)
  at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:726)
  at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:818)
  at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:806)
  at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The ParseFile is a jpg which is uploaded and then put into a ParseObject called `ImageObject`. The `ImageObject` has several other parameters like caption, width, height which upload and download correctly. The image itself uploads correctly as confirmed through the dashboard. Only during the download I get the above exception.

This is my upload code

```
file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d(tag, "Successfully uploaded image file");

            ParseObject image = new ParseObject("imageObject");  //Create new Image-ParseObject and set values
            image.put("author", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
            image.put("imageFile", file);
            image.put("caption", caption);

            image.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if(e==null){
                        Log.d(tag, "Successfully saved image file to object");
                    }else{
                        Log.d(tag, "Failed to save image file to object", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.d(tag, "Failed to save image", e);
        }
    }
```

my download code is pretty much `ParseFile.getFile()` after I have retrieved all the `ImageObjects` through a ParseQuery.

I Followed Line 43 of ParseAWSRequest.java and I found this,

```
if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300 || statusCode == 304) {
    // OK
} else {
    String action = method == ParseHttpRequest.Method.GET ? "Download from" : "Upload to";
    return Task.forError(new ParseException(ParseException.CONNECTION_FAILED, String.format(
        "%s S3 failed. %s", action, response.getReasonPhrase())));
}
```

This and the "Permanently removed" points to my nginx reverse proxy, which returns a 301 code in the redirect to https. Unfortunately I am not sure where to proceed from here.

Extra information,
I have blocked port 80(http) in the firewall for a test and it seems that for the download parse-android-sdk is trying to download from http. Which is odd because I have specified my parse-server link with "https", and the fact that upload is working fine. I can see the uploaded image using dashboard on my server.

Using,

- Parse Server 2.2.13
- Parse Android SDK 1.13.1
- Parse Dashboard 1.0.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to this issue just by directly downloading the file. I used `ParseFile.getUrl()` method to get the url and then use that to download and use the file.

In my case it was `.jpg` files. And then I used an external library that takes care of all the downloading/caching/loading into imageviews.

Both of these libraries work well

https://github.com/koush/ion

http://square.github.io/picasso/